# How to initializing an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I need to initialize a multidimensional array with the following structure:

```
{"String value", {"string-a", string_b", ...}}
```

So the first dimension is simply a string and the second element is an variable length array of string()

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y13tek7e.aspx

Comment: A `Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))` is the superior decision, unless you *need* to use a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: I do indeed need to use the array .. believe me I'd much rather use the dictionary :)

Comment: An array? Why? The indices of an array are integers; the equivalence getting string-based indices is precisely the Dictionary. You might also create a custom class. Can you please explain your exact constraints and why a dictionary is not applicable?

Comment: I know you are trying to be helpful, but the reason for my constraints are irrelevant. This is what needs to be done, if you can help me with the correct initialization, that's all I need.

Comment: Well, have an array of objects then.

Comment: (sure I am trying to help) But you have to explain your constraints such that we can advise you the best way through. An array is a collection whose indices are given by integers. If you want a collection which takes different indices you would have to use other thing: either a dictionary or create your own class (and create an array from it, as suggested by Yuriy right now). But you need to be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since the first entry is a String and not an Array of String, your data does not fit the model for a multi-dimensional array, or even a jagged array.

You could declare an Array of Objects:

```
Dim data() As Object = {"String value", New String() {"string-a", "string_b"}}
```

**But that is really not a good idea.**

Another option could be to use a *Tuple* like this:

```
    Dim data As New Tuple(Of String, String())("String value", {"string-a", "string_b"})

    Debug.Print(data.Item1)
    For Each value As String In data.Item2
        Debug.Print(value)
    Next
```

But then you might as well just use a custom Class as suggested by the others.

Can you give more details as to how this data will be used?  That might lead to a better solution for you...